# Shopware5 order confirmation email event

Tags: symfony, email, events, shopware

After a long investigation, I am not able to find the correct event to use JUST before the order confirmation email is sent.

I need to add a value in the s_order_attributes table which will be included in the email template.

I tried many events (e.g. checkout) but they are all triggered after the email ones.

thanks !

Comment: Is it suitable to set this value on placing the order? What kind of value is it?

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens This is a value coming from one of my resources files (it's a number) and wich increases at each order.
The only problem is that I don't know How to add this value BEFORE the email is send to the buyer.
In the past, I was adding this value in the 'sOrder::setPaymentStatus::after' & 'sOrder::sSaveOrder::after' BUT these 2 events are triggered after the email (apparently).
Because the email field is empty but when I go in the s_order_attributes table, the field is correctly filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the code when the email is sent](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/7e57739eb84b39b7e2fe31377303a086f9d7598f/engine/Shopware/Core/sOrder.php#L884) I assume there are two events you can try. You can either try `Shopware_Modules_Order_SendMail_FilterVariables` or `sOrder::sendMail::before`. These are executed right before the sending. If the attributes are not loaded from the database anymore in that moment you can set the public variables in sOrder to change the values that get into the mail. This might help you out as well but I prefer the `FilterVariables` event as it gives you direct access to the variables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I made some tests and I will use the sOrder::sendMail::before.

I have a last question, I need to get the orderId in the function I call when this event occurs. 
I tried with $args->get('id'); $args->get('orderId'); but did not get what I wanted. 
And I am not able to var_dump($args) so how could I get the orderId?

Comment: At this event you should be able to do `$args->getArgs()[0]['ordernumber']` to get the ordernumber. The order id is not present at this point but the ordernumber is unique as well and helps you at querying the order id.